# Altering stored procedure displays `Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of left function` error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[OptimizedGetArticlePostAMP] 
     (@PostID int)     
--[ OptimizedGetArticlePostAMP] 678161      
-- 732490        
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SectionId int, @datediff int                                    
    DECLARE @postdate datetime

    SELECT 
        P.PostId, P.SectionID, P.PostName, 
        MP.MetaTitle, P.Postdate, P.PostAuthor, P.IsApproved,
        MP.Metadescription, MP.Metakeywords, 
        P.TotalViews, P.Subject, P.FormattedBody,                      
        MV.Isvideo, MV.VideoCode, MV.VideoCaption, 
        A.DrComment, A.SpanishURL, PS.RedirectUrl,
        MP.Canonical as Canonical, PS.StatusId,
        dbo.[ GetCommentCountForPost](@PostId) as TotalReplies,  
        PRD.StoryImage, PRD.StoryContent,                             
        MH.LastModifiedDate,
        REPLACE(LEFT(P.FormattedBody, CHARINDEX('</strong>', P.FormattedBody) - 1),'<p><strong>By','') <--This Line shows **error**
    FROM 
        csposts P 
    LEFT JOIN
        NewsletterDetails A ON (P.Postid = A.postid)       
    LEFT JOIN
        PostStatus PS ON (PS.postid = p.postid)
    LEFT JOIN  
        PostMetatags MP ON (P.postid = MP.Postid)              
    LEFT JOIN
        postVideo MV ON (P.postid = MV.Postid)
    LEFT JOIN 
        CSPostAttachments PA ON P.PostId = PA.PostId 
                             AND PA.contenttype LIKE 'audio/mpeg' 
                             AND PA.FILENAME LIKE '%.mp3' 
                             AND PA.isremote = 1
    LEFT JOIN  
        PostRelatedData PRD ON P.PostId = PRD.PostId
    LEFT JOIN  
        PostReferences PR on P.PostId = PR.PostId
    CROSS APPLY 
        (SELECT TOP 1 LastModifiedDate 
         FROM ArticleModifiedHistory 
         WHERE ArticleModifiedHistory.Postid = P.postid 
         ORDER BY LastModifiedDate desc) MH
    WHERE
        P.Postid = @Postid     
END
```

Since I have used LEFT function it shows below error:

> Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of left function.

Please let me know what I need to change to make it run.

Comment: Why isn't it a `varchar(max)`?

Comment: Have you tried changing this `P.FormattedBody` to this `CAST(P.FormattedBody as nvarchar(max))`?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Thank you all...!!

Answer (score 0):

Left function does not accept ntext data type. Like gofr1 said first cast it to a nvarchar or use the substring function which accepts ntext parameter.

Comment: I suggest you to remove this answer, it is more suited as a comment. :) Or rephrase your answer. Just advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
LEFT([Column], 123)
```

by

```
SUBSTRING([Column], 1, 123)
```

SUBSTRING is happy to accept an ntext data type.

Reference: [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql), [LEFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql)